# What's the story behind "The Malachim's Niggun " of the Karliner chassidim?

Tags: music, chasidut-hasidism, provenance

What's the story behind the Karliner niggun for Chapter 130 in Tehilim that they refer to as "The Malachim's Niggun"? Is it true that Rav Aharon Karliner claims to have heard the malachim singing this niggun?

Comment: have you a link, I am interested to listen this song.

Comment: @kouty - I'd enjoy hearing the song as well.